# Grails Acegi Plugin - how to update cache?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm having a problem with Acegi Plugin. The problem is that Acegi caches user info. If I update roles or password the change doesn't appear immediately. For a while I can even log out and log in with previous password. I found 2 solutions [JIRA](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILSPLUGINS-1691).

1. Set cacheUsers = false in SecurityConfig.groovy
2. Use special filter to update securityContext

Both solutions work. Unfortunately, both produce loads of database queries.

Users are updated only in UserService.update(..) and I can expect that they will be updated rarely. Is there any chance to immediately update securityContext. It's no problem for the current user. But can I do it even for another logged-in user?? e.g. if admin changes roles/password for some user

Answer (score 1):

cacheUsers = false is the best option. It doesn't produce "loads" of queries, just one per login. The slight extra cost outweighs the annoying side effects of caching.